# How to expect on method calls that has inline new instance creations in easymock

Tags: junit4, spring-jdbc, easymock

We have following code structure in our code

```
namedParamJdbcTemplate.query(buildMyQuery(request),new MapSqlParameterSource(),myresultSetExtractor);
```

and

```
namedParamJdbcTemplate.query(buildMyQuery(request),new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(mybean),myresultSetExtractor);
```

How can I expect these method calls without using isA matcher?

Assume that I am passing mybean and myresultSetExtractor in request for the methods in which above code lies.

Comment: Could you show a psedu-code of the test you're attempting to write, and explain why it does not work? As the question currently stands, it's a tad hard to understand. Thanks!

Comment: I am using isA for now. But I cannot use it from now. Can I achieve this without isA?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
Easymock.expect(namedParamJdbcTemplateMock.query(EasyMock.anyObject(String.class),EasyMock.anyObject(Map.class),EasyMock.anyObject(ResultSetExtractor.class))).andReturn(...);
```

likewise you can do mocking for other Methods as well.

hope this helps!

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use [PowerMock to tell the constructors to return mock instances](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor), then you'll have to use some form of Matcher.

`isA` is a good one.
As is `anyObject` which is suggested in another answer.

If I were you though, I'd be using Captures. A capture is an object that holds the value you provided to a method so that you can later perform assertions on the captured values and check they have the state you wanted. So you could write something like this:

```
Capture<MapSqlParameterSource> captureMyInput = new Capture<MapSqlParameterSource>();

//I'm not entirely sure of the types you're using, but the important one is the capture method 
Easymock.expect(namedParamJdbcTemplateMock.query(
    EasyMock.anyObject(Query.class), EasyMock.capture(captureMyInput), EasyMock.eq(myresultSetExtractor.class))).andReturn(...);

MapSqlParameterSource caughtValue = captureMyInput.getValue(); 
//Then perform your assertions on the state of your caught value.
```

There are lots of examples floating around for how captures work, but [this blog post](https://blog.trifork.com/2008/09/22/easymock-capturing-arguments-passed-to-mock-objects/comment-page-1/) is a decent example.